# Wrap components of npm and export it as custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

There's a problem installing 3rd party components from npm. For example there's a dropdown react module, I can use it easily in my module. But I have to declare its style and other dependencies of the component in many modules of mine.

Like for this component

I have to inject its style in every of my module

```
import 'icheck/skins/all.css';
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a dropdown library, which we'll call `Dropdown`, you could create a custom module, called `MyDropdown`, where you import your CSS and export `Dropdown`.

All other modules that use `Dropdown` would import it from `MyDropdown`.  The CSS will have been loaded along with it.

Comment: how would the file look like? I did import css but I got error of exporting.

Comment: says the file name is input.js, after I import all the css of Dropdown, can I do export 'Dropdown' ?

Comment: So, I do this frequently.  For example, I do this w/ `react-select`.  My `select.js` file has a custom export React class (called `Select`) which I import elsewhere throughout my app.  At the top of this module, I import my custom CSS.  Can you provide the specific error you're seeing?  Maybe your custom module as well?

Comment: I try to do this in my input.js. import 'icheck/skins/square/all.css';
export 'react-icheck'

Comment: Try creating a custom class that wraps around react-icheck. Something that can handle and pass through any props you may want to assign when instantiating later. Then export your custom class, not the npm library

Comment: Does the custom component need to have render function?

Comment: Yes, it does need a render function. It is where you would instantiate your npm module and pass along any props